# How do I get MYSQL to join a whole table?

Tags: mysql

I have a SELECT query that returns the response based on an unique ID, so I always get just one row.
I thought that I could save my machine an extra SELECT query if I simply added the prices table to the result, and read them to memory later on.

Would that be a good approach or am I missing something ?
(I tried it out and seems to get the job done)

```
SELECT * 
FROM subscriptions
LEFT JOIN prices ON 1=1
WHERE subscriptions.ID = 100
```

**edit: The prices table has no ID. I just need to get the complete table, I used to have a different SELECT just for that**

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP...

Comment: You should join the prices table on the subscription ID (or other ID), so that it knows which prices to return you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a terrible idea... you should join the subscriptions table to the prices table using the foreign key that you (supposedly/should) have.

Assuming your prices table has a subscription ID column then your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM subscriptions LEFT JOIN prices ON subscriptions.ID=prices.ID
WHERE subscriptions.ID=100
```

Comment: the prices table is a general table, and I was thinking of reading the whole table in this one SELECT. would you think that I need to use another SELECT just to read the prices ?

Comment: @Ted The price table shouldn't be a general table. But in case you want to stick with that approach (REAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALLLY BAD approach for reasons described below) then I suggest selecting the price table in another select statement and storing it in some kind of local structure. Believe me what your trying to do will KILL your server!

Comment: Since my price table is very small, and I only have just one result on the right side, I don't understand why I'd have so much of a server slowdown, because I am doing the same thing on another SELECT.

Answer (score 3):

What this will do is produce a cartesian join - not too bad since you're limiting the 'subscriptions' side of things to a single record, but will still produce as many rows as there's records in the price side. Where this gets bad is when you've got multiple rows on both sides. Then you get `n x m` results - think of how big the result set would be if you had 50,000 subscriptions joined against 1000 prices: 50,000 x 1,000 = 50 million result rows.

Answer (score 2):

First off, this approach is going to be much less clear what you're doing than two SELECT statements *unless there is an actual relation between the tables.* Second, it's probably going to be slower, because you're transferring much more data (each row of prices additionally gets all the fields from subscriptions copied).

If subscriptions and prices *are* related, you want to change that ON condition to use the relation, so you're only pulling the data you need.

```
SELECT *
FROM subscriptions s LEFT JOIN prices p ON (s.subscription_id = p.subscription_id)
WHERE s.subscription_id = 100
```

One thing you definitely don't want to do is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM subscriptions s LEFT JOIN prices p ON (1=1)
```

as that'd pull the full Cartesian product. Once your tables get sufficiently large, that will run you out of temporary table space.

Answer (score 2):

why your condition have **1=1** ?
I thing that is's must something like this:

```
SELECT s.*,p.*
FROM subscriptions as s
LEFT JOIN prices as p ON p.product_id=s.product_id
WHERE s.ID = 100
```

show me your full fields of tables subscriptions and prices to help for you

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
SELECT * 
FROM subscriptions, prices
WHERE subscriptions.ID = 100
```

You'll get horrible results like this, but it seems this is what you wanted.

The table with less rows will have its rows repeating. Again, this is **not** a good practice.
 Use two SELECTs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cross join http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join

which means your resultset will contain as many rows as you have in the `prices` table.

So I guess it is not a good idea